# Compiling issues with Rust language: starting with 'Hello World'

Tags: rust, ld, cc

I am using a up2date Linux Mint system which I am using for lots of trial and error projects.
Today I stumbled upon Rust and wanted to try it out.

So far so good. Installing Rust was easy and simple.

Used the suggested method, set the environment-variable and performed  a update:

- `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`
- `source $HOME/.cargo/env`
- `rustup update`

So far so good, no errors or other disturbing signals. So after the previous I tried, just like everybody does, compiling the 'Hello world'-example. And here it went sideways. The error:

```
...
$ rustc main.rs
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" [....... ]"-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

My system has cc installed: cc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, if you have a problem, try to find out if somebody else had a smiliar problem and if there was a useful answer. Maybe this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299511/missing-crt1-and-crti-when-crosscompiling. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436035/whats-the-usage-of-mcrt1-o-and-scrt1-o for details.

Comment: Duplicate of [Compiling problems: cannot find crt1.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer that's working for me in other post for Clang: [Compiling problems: cannot find crt1.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o).

Answer given by Dmitry Pavlenko works just fine for me too:

> The problem is you likely only have the gcc for your current
>   architecture and that's 64bit. You need the 32bit support files. For
>   that, you need to install
>
> sudo apt install gcc-multilib